# Splitting strings into numbers (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, floating-point

This is likely a very basic question. I have a text file with lines of float values. For example, the text file `myRandomizedFile.txt` looks like this:

```
1992.0  12.999  0.0 0.0 7980.0
1991.0  11.593  0.625   0.0 7997.0
1992.0  12.999  0.625   0.0 7989.0
1992.0  12.999  0.375   0.0 7998.0
1994.0  14.989  0.0 0.0 7982.0
110.0   42.945  1.0 0.0 7973.0
1992.0  15.077  0.125   0.0 7973.0
492.0   8.824   0.25    1.0 7980.0
1991.0  20.401  0.0 0.0 7997.0
1993.0  12.999  0.625   0.0 7934.0
```

However, when I try to access these numbers through indices, all I get is each string character. For example, if I want to access the top left number, `1992.0`, by trying to use index of `allTen[0][0]`, it tells me that `allTen[0] = 1`.

Below is my code:

```
f = open("../BestTen.txt")                      #Randomize the parameter set order for pairing
o = open("../myRandomizedFile.txt", "w")
entire_file = f.read()
lines_in_list = entire_file.split("\n")
num_lines = len(lines_in_list)
random_nums = random.sample(xrange(num_lines), num_lines)
for i in random_nums:
    o.write(lines_in_list[i] + "\n")
o.close()
f.close()

rand = open("../myRandomizedFile.txt")          #Pairs up lines (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10)
allTen = rand.read()
print "AllTen: ", allTen
print "AllTen[0]: ", allTen[0]
ind1Aff = allTen[0][0]
ind2Aff = allTen[1][0]
ind1Vff = allTen[0][1]
```

The bottom-most line is giving me an `IndexError` because `allTen[0]` is `1` instead of `[1992.0 12.999 0.0 0.0 7980]`. **How do I get the program to recognize this as a list of floats rather than a bunch of characters (strings)?**

Comment: You have to `split` the string first. Try `allTen.split()[0]`

Comment: You might consider `pandas`: `pd.read_csv('myRandomizedFile.txt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
with open("myRandomizedFile.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    allTen = np.array([float(i) for l in lines for i in l.split()]).reshape((len(lines), 5))

print (allTen[0][0])
```

**Output**

```
1992.0
```

Comment: If you're going to use NumPy, I think it's better to avoid creating a list first, e.g. use `np.genfromtxt`.

Comment: I am just a big fan of list comprehensions ;) Nothing against using NumPy

Comment: Nothing wrong with a list comprehension. But, in that case, you don't need `np.array`.

Comment: I needed it for `reshape`. There might be several solutions to get around it though

Answer (score 1):

You can use NumPy with [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). Here's a demo:

```
from io import BytesIO

x = BytesIO(b"""1992.0  12.999  0.0 0.0 7980.0
1991.0  11.593  0.625   0.0 7997.0
1992.0  12.999  0.625   0.0 7989.0
1992.0  12.999  0.375   0.0 7998.0
1994.0  14.989  0.0 0.0 7982.0
110.0   42.945  1.0 0.0 7973.0
1992.0  15.077  0.125   0.0 7973.0
492.0   8.824   0.25    1.0 7980.0
1991.0  20.401  0.0 0.0 7997.0
1993.0  12.999  0.625   0.0 7934.0""")

res = np.genfromtxt(x)
```

Result:

```
print(res)

[[  1.99200000e+03   1.29990000e+01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    7.98000000e+03]
 [  1.99100000e+03   1.15930000e+01   6.25000000e-01   0.00000000e+00
    7.99700000e+03]
 ...
 [  1.99100000e+03   2.04010000e+01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    7.99700000e+03]
 [  1.99300000e+03   1.29990000e+01   6.25000000e-01   0.00000000e+00
    7.93400000e+03]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You normally have to read files in array format and strip the new line character and split the list, then you got you solution.

```
    with open('myRandomizedFile.txt', 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        data = [l.strip().split() for l in data]
        print(data[0][0])
     #output as: data[0][0]: 1992.0
     #            data[1]: ['1991.0', '11.593', '0.625', '0.0', '7997.0']
```